# Write a logical expression for "Everyone who has studied medicine and practises medicine is someones doctor."

Tags: logic

This question was on my exam. I cannot remember the exact sentence but this was basically it. How can I write a logical expression for this sentence using universal and existential quantifiers? Can someone explain to me please?

Comment: $S \:  \mbox{AND} \: P \implies D$?

Comment: Or more complicatedly, perhaps: If $X$ is the set of people then: For all $n \in X$ we have $$S(n) \: \mbox{AND} \: P(n) \implies [\exists m \in X \: \mbox{such that} \:  n=D(m)]$$ where $S(n)$ is true if person $n$ studies medicine, $P(n)$ is true if person $n$ practices medicine, and $D(m)$ is the doctor for person $m$.

Comment: Can you please explain which sentences did you assign the letters for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Everyone who has studied medicine and practices medicine is someones doctor."

So it looks like we have a few main concepts we need to be able to describe:

1. A person who has studied medicine: Call it $S(x)$ when $x$ has studied medicine
2. A person who practices medicine: Call it $P(x)$ when $x$ practices medicine
3. A person who is another person's doctor: Call it $D(x, y)$ when $x$ is $y$'s doctor

(alternatively, you could say $x = D(y)$, if you're ok with having equality as a concept rather than just using propositions)

So $S(x) \wedge P(x)$ means "$x$ studied medicine and $x$ practices medicine", i.e. it represents a person who both studied and currently practices medicine.

To describe "is someone's (i.e. an unspecified but existent person's) doctor", we mean that we know that there is someone for whom $x$ is that person's doctor, i.e. $\exists y\  D(x, y)$.

Hence, "Everyone who has studied medicine and practises medicine is someones doctor." becomes "For all people $x$ where $x$ has studied medicine and $x$ practices medicine, there is another person $y$ for whom $x$ is $y$'s doctor", or in our current notation:

$$\forall x \left(S(x) \wedge P(x) \rightarrow \left( \exists y\ D(x, y)\right) \right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

You first need an impicit domain and some predicates.

For the domain of people:

- $S(x)$ "$x$ has studied medicine",
- $P(x)$ "$x$  practices medicine",
- $D(x,y)$ "$x$ is the doctor of $y$".

So "Everybody who studied medicine and practices medicine, is somebody's doctor."

So "Everybody $x$: $S(x)\wedge P(x)$, is for somebody $y$: $D(x,y)$."

$$\forall x~((S(x)\wedge P(x))\to \exists y~D(x,y))$$

Or in Prenex canonical form:

$$\forall x~\exists y~((S(x)\wedge P(x))\to D(x,y))$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!